# Metric tensor for a distribution of Mass and Energy

Tags: tensors

I am sorry that this is $not$ a complete math question but I was not allowed to post it on Physics Section, so here we go....

Anyways, The Einstein Field Equation describes the relationship of Mass, Energy, Pressure and the curvature of spacetime For now, don't care about the values on the RHS,

$$R_{\mu\nu} - 1/2 R g_{\mu\nu} = 8πT_{\mu\nu}$$

(This is the equation when $c=1$)
So I think of expanding the LHS in terms of the Metric Tensor ($g_{\mu\nu}$) but this would give me a utterly disturbing equation.

So for a value on RHS, how will I calculate $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: What makes you think there is an easy way to solve it? What makes you think there is a way to solve it at all?

Comment: I don't know I think it's impossible...